# How to get sum of differences from two dates in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to sum of differences from starttime and endtime in minutes.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56cd544df7851e850d8b4573"),
    "user_id" : "281",
    "document_id" : "1455614372.pdf",
    "page_number" : "1",
    "starttime" : ISODate("48118-03-20T01:35:14Z"),
    "endtime" : ISODate("48118-03-20T04:29:10Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56cd544df7851e850d8b4574"),
    "user_id" : "281",
    "document_id" : "1455614372.pdf",
    "page_number" : "1",
    "starttime" : ISODate("48118-03-20T14:29:49Z"),
    "endtime" : ISODate("48118-06-22T12:52:36Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56cd544df7851e850d8b4575"),
    "user_id" : "281",
    "document_id" : "1455614372.pdf",
    "page_number" : "2",
    "starttime" : ISODate("48118-03-20T04:29:10Z"),
    "endtime" : ISODate("48118-03-20T14:29:49Z")
}
```

my collection name is pdftracker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't say which fields you want to group on, but assuming you want a "user_id" and "document_id" combination. Whatever it's just the `_id` field in the following [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group) statement.

As for the "interval", then date math is on your side, and when you [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract) one `Date` object from another, then the result is the "difference" represented in "milliseconds". So that again just takes a little conversion:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "user_id": "$user_id", "document_id": "$document_id" },
        "totalMinites": {
            "$sum": {
                "$divide": [
                    { "$subtract": [ "$endtime", "$starttime" ] },
                    1000 * 60
                ]
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Simple math rolled into [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum) for the total on the grouping. And 1000 milliseconds multiplied by 60 seconds as a divisor on a millisecond result does the conversion to minutes.